# A slight twist in Folland 5.1.12a)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $M $ be a subspace of $X$.

I want to show that $\| x+ M\|= \inf \|x+y\| : y \in M$ defines a norm on $X/M$ if and only if $X$ is closed.

I've showed that if $M$ is a closed proper subspace then $\| x+ M\|= \inf \|x+y\| : y \in M$ defines a norm on $X/M$.

But I'm not sure how to do the other direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n) \subset M$ and $x_n \to x$. Then $\|x+M\|\leq \|x-x_n\|$ for all $n$  since $-x_n \in M$. Hence $\|x+M\|=0$. This implies $x+M=0$ and hence $x \in M$.

Comment: Hi, may I ask why $\leq$ instead of $\geq$ for the inequality? Thank you!

Comment: @2pirsquared By definition $\|x+M\| =\inf \{\|x+y\|: y \in M\}$ so $\|x+M\| \leq \|x+y\|$ for any $y \in M$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me complement some argument from the previous author. If $x\in\mathcal{X}$ and $\|x+\mathcal{M}\|=0$, then choose $\{y_n\}\in\mathcal{M}$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x+y_n\|=0$. Follows that $x=-\lim_{n\to\infty}(-y_n)\in\mathcal{M}$. If $x\in\mathcal{X}$ and for arbitrary $a\neq 0$ (the case $a=0$ follows),
$$\|a(x+\mathcal{M})\|=\|ax+\mathcal{M}\|=\inf_{y\in\mathcal{M}}\|ax+y\|=|a|\inf_{y\in\mathcal{M}}\|x+a^{-1}y\|=|a|\|x+\mathcal{M}\|$$
For $x,y\in\mathcal{M}$,

$$\|(x+y)+\mathcal{M}\|=\inf_{z\in\mathcal{M}}\|x+y+z\|=\inf_{w,z\in\mathcal{M}}\|x+y+w+z\|\\\leq\inf_{w,z\in\mathcal{M}}\left(\|x+y\|+\|w+z\|\right)=\inf_{w\in\mathcal{M}}\|x+w\|+\inf_{z\in\mathcal{M}}\|y+z\|=\|x+\mathcal{M}\|+\|y+\mathcal{M}\|$$